# Insert object to child array based on id in the child object

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have conversation object as follows,

```
{
  "buyer": {
    "userId": "eu-central-1:1080fb20-5271-478f-97f0-0223ded70e3c",
    "Name": "John"
  },
  "seller": {
    "userId": "eu-central-1:b3e5afe9-f4d9-4c90-b3ac-7b24a465c996",
    "Name": "Doe"
  },
  "conversationId": "2c418465-1154-4153-850b-4ea504877c36",
  "messages": [{
    "date": "12/23/2013",
    "text": "hi how is it going\n",
    "receiverId": "eu-central-1:b3e5afe9-f4d9-4c90-b3ac-7b24a465c996",
    "senderId": "eu-central-1:1080fb20-5271-478f-97f0-0223ded70e3c"
  }]
}
```

In the above I need to replace the messages object, I need to add a new property named sender by checking the id in the conversation Object and assign it.

Output will be:

```
{
  "buyer": {
    "userId": "eu-central-1:1080fb20-5271-478f-97f0-0223ded70e3c",
    "Name": "John"
  },
  "seller": {
    "userId": "eu-central-1:b3e5afe9-f4d9-4c90-b3ac-7b24a465c996",
    "Name": "Doe"
  },
  "conversationId": "2c418465-1154-4153-850b-4ea504877c36",
  "messages": [{
    "date": "12/23/2013",
    "text": "hi how is it going\n",
    "receiverId": "eu-central-1:b3e5afe9-f4d9-4c90-b3ac-7b24a465c996",
    "senderId": "eu-central-1:1080fb20-5271-478f-97f0-0223ded70e3c",
    "sender": {
      "userId": "eu-central-1:1080fb20-5271-478f-97f0-0223ded70e3c",
      "Name": "John"
    },
    "reciever": {
      "userId": "eu-central-1:b3e5afe9-f4d9-4c90-b3ac-7b24a465c996",
      "Name": "Doe"
    }
  }]
}
```

I tried with a for loop, which works fine. But is there a way to do it in few lines using loadash or vanila javascript?

Comment: You could also use `.forEach` or even better: `.reduce` by converting your object into keys. But I wonder if your `"sender"` property is being loaded async or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `map` your object `messages` and transform it accordingly:

```
obj.messages.map(function(m){
    if(m.senderId === obj.buyer.userId){
      m.sender = Object.assign({}, obj.buyer);
      m.receiver = Object.assign({}, obj.seller);
    }else if(m.senderId === obj.seller.userId){
      m.sender = Object.assign({}, obj.seller);
      m.receiver = Object.assign({}, obj.buyer);
    }
    return m;
});
```

**Demo:**

Here's a working demo:

```js
var obj = {
  "buyer": {
    "userId": "eu-central-1:1080fb20-5271-478f-97f0-0223ded70e3c",
    "Name": "John"
  },
  "seller": {
    "userId": "eu-central-1:b3e5afe9-f4d9-4c90-b3ac-7b24a465c996",
    "Name": "Doe"
  },
  "conversationId": "2c418465-1154-4153-850b-4ea504877c36",
  "messages": [{
    "date": "12/23/2013",
    "text": "hi how is it going\n",
    "receiverId": "eu-central-1:b3e5afe9-f4d9-4c90-b3ac-7b24a465c996",
    "senderId": "eu-central-1:1080fb20-5271-478f-97f0-0223ded70e3c"
  }]
};

obj.messages.map(function(m){
    if(m.senderId === obj.buyer.userId){
      m.sender = Object.assign({}, obj.buyer);
      m.receiver = Object.assign({}, obj.seller);
    }else if(m.senderId === obj.seller.userId){
      m.sender = Object.assign({}, obj.seller);
      m.receiver = Object.assign({}, obj.buyer);
    }
    return m;
});

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: i am not using jquery

Comment: Where is lodlash?

Comment: @faceturn I edited the answer with `Object.assign()` instead.

Comment: @mok I gave it in pure JS, there's no need for lodash.

Comment: But it's even tagged with lodlash

Comment: Yes it's tagged with lodash but it's better when it v=can be achieved with JS only. :)

Comment: Ok,now the answer is pure JS and the OP has edited the question.

Comment: how to do with typescript?

Comment: @faceturn well `typescript` is built on pure `javascript`, so this can be used in `typescript`.

Comment: How is that? Can you show a demo? what error do you get?

Comment: if(m.senderId === obj.buyer.userId){ i cannot access this.conversation.buyer.userId

Comment: What's conversation? I think in your case `obj.buyer.userId` will be `obj.conversationId`.